# c++ opengl glm combine rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Let's say I want to rotate 30° on the x axis, then 60° to the y axis, how to do this with glm?

I tried this to combine them :

```
mat4 xRotation, yRotation, zRotation;
xRotation = rotate( mat4( 1.0f ), rotation.x, vec3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );
yRotation = rotate( mat4( 1.0f ), rotation.y, vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) );
zRotation = rotate( mat4( 1.0f ), rotation.z, vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) );

return zRotation * yRotation * xRotation;
```

But the resulted rotation is weird.

Comment: How is the result weird?

Comment: Seem's like the rotation is inversed in certain axis, but the problem doesn't come from rotation combination.

Comment: Don't forget you are rotating around the local axis and when rotating around the x axis the y axis is rotated too.